# jquery validate conflict with jquery tools

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate, jquery-tools

I've used jquery validate to validate a form and submit for processing. All works well and I'm happy with the form.

I decided to add jquery tools to the form to use the dateinput feature. I can get the calendar pick up and works well.

However, I have not set any rules to validate the date text box called "mydate" but when I select any date in the future it immediately comes up with an invalid date, validate is doing something to check the date and not allowing future dates.

I removed validate script from my page and the date input works as expected.

SO there is something automatic in the validation. HOw can I disable validate for this input box (even though I have not set up any rules) or how can I get round this problem

Thank you

HI

The class for the element was 'date', I renamed it to 'mydate' prior to posting question as I assumed validate was picking that up as a date but still got caught.

I have taken the route of dropping jquery tools for now and using the user interface one instead. All working so far so a change of direction required

Thank you

Comment: what css classes does the input have? jQuery validate will attach date validation to anything with the class `date`, for example. Edit: added the full list as an answer.

Comment: jQuery Tools has never impressed me.  It requires tons of markup, always out of date with jQuery and very buggy.  I'd dump it for something more reliable and compliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the classes that jquery validate will automatically attach valiation to. Avoid using these class names to avoid automatic rules.

```
classRuleSettings: {
    required: {required: true},
    email: {email: true},
    url: {url: true},
    date: {date: true},
    dateISO: {dateISO: true},
    dateDE: {dateDE: true},
    number: {number: true},
    numberDE: {numberDE: true},
    digits: {digits: true},
    creditcard: {creditcard: true}
}
```

Comment: I did have it as date but changed it before posting question to mydate but problem still occurred